# Download a PDF and rename it?

Tags: php

I'm working on a little script to save some time. My script takes a given URL to a PDF and I want to download the PDF to the local computer, say to /Downloads but I want to rename the file with a name taken from a form.

Is this possible with PHP?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this to rename:

```
rename(oldname,newname)
```

http://php.net/manual/en/function.rename.php

Use this to force download a pdf file:

```
<?php
header('Content-type: application/pdf');
header('Content-disposition: attachment; filename=filename.pdf');
readfile("http://manuals.info.apple.com/en/iphone_user_guide.pdf");
?>
```

Comment: Worked perfectly. Had to remove the first header as that threw and error saying headers had already been sent. But works fine without it.